# Where to write .s file for assembly

Tags: assembly

I believe I'm working on an x86-64 and I need to write a .s file, such as example.s, assemble then disassemble the file to get the machine code generated from the assembly language.

I'm new to this, so where would I go about writing a .s file? textedit? sublime? emacs? right now im working in terminal. All I know is that i need to use gcc to assemble and objdump to disassemble.

Thanks !

Comment: Use literally anything that has the ability to save plaintext files.

Comment: You're asking how to edit a text file?

Comment: wouldn't it save as a .txt file though? i think im misunderstanding something - does it not need to be a .s file?

Comment: Just name it `.s`. It is a text file. Also, you can ask the assembler for a listing, you don't have to objdump.

Comment: actually i just got it, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use any text editor. Sublime text is fine.